How to exclude or change the package.json stored insed an electron asar archive?
I noticed that an asar archive of my app built with electron-forge and extracted with the npx @electron/asar extract my-app/out/{my_app_package_dir}/resources/app.asar extraction_dir command contains the same package.json as the my-app/package.json.
It exposes development dependencies and build logic scripts that can be used for reverse engineering, which is undesirable.
How can I alter the content of resulting package.json in asar archive and keep its integrity?
